# duplicate rows will be insert into table when i use 0 for primary key

Tags: php

When i use this SQL command, duplicate rows will insert.

SQL command is:

```
$dbh = mysql_connect(db_host, db_user, db_pass);
mysql_select_db(db_name, $dbh);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO test VALUES(0, '1')");
```

this happened just when i use 0 for first field that is primary and **auto_increment**

Comment: No, it's not PDO. It's **your code** which calling this insert twice. Go figure

Comment: I found that it happens even using mysql_query command. now that's the full code i have tested.

Comment: Show the full code. What you are showing is *not* the full code. With a 99.99999% probability, you are calling the script twice. [SELECT isn't broken](http://www.travisswicegood.com/2009/01/04/select-isn-t-broken/)

Comment: that's the full source, i say it's happens just when i use 0 for primary key.

Comment: it's rewrite issue again I suppose

Comment: @Pekka - Let me give it a try. @Omid - Take your query and run it directly against the DB in whatever query tool is available for your database platform and you will see the double insert doesn't happen. It is your code. This snippet is somehow getting called twice.

Comment: @col either that, or something like the good old `<link rel='stylesheet' src=''>` issue @JohnFx yeah

Comment: @Omid: that's not the entirety of a PHP source file.  So it's not the full source, trivially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strangely the problem was firefox browser cache!
I just tried to reset firefox in safe mode and the problem is solved now.

Answer (score 1):

I fail to see the problem:

```
mysql> use test;
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed
mysql> create table test (x int primary key auto_increment, y varchar(1));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into test values (0, '1');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into test values (0, '1');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into test values (0, '1');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from test;
+---+------+
| x | y    |
+---+------+
| 1 | 1    |
| 2 | 1    |
| 3 | 1    |
+---+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into test values (3,'1');
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '3' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

This is standard MySQL behavior. Inserting a 0 into a primary key/auto_increment column is the same as inserting a null - MySQL will re-write the value into the auto_increment value.

Answer (score 0):

you need to declare your insert columns.  instead of a blind insert you would want it to go something like this:

column names in table A (id, name, address, phone)
id is set to auto increment

INSERT INTO `table A` (name, address, phone) values ('John Doe', '123 Street', '1231231234')

doing it this way will allow the auto increment to work in the id column.  if you need to insert multiple rows at the same time you can do it like this:

INSERT INTO `table A` 
(name, address, phone) values 
('John Doe', '123 Street', '1231231234')
,('Jane Doe', '124 Street', '1231231235')
,('Joe Doe', '126 Street', '1231231236')

Each row will be given a unique id.  If you then did

SELECT * from `table A` you would get this as a result:

1, John Doe, 123 Street, 1231231234

2, Jane Doe, 124 Street, 1231231235

3, Jake Doe, 126 Street, 1231231236